# How to get my email macro to work again through MSAccess

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, ms-access-2016, cdo.message

My company has a database that was built for us,and suddenly the module we were using to send emails isnt working anymore. I'm told that security measures have changed, so I'm trying to figure out how to update the settings and make this work again. Unfortunately, I don't really know how half these functions work. Any ideas?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit



Public Function EmailReceiptByGeneric( _
    ByVal strReceipt As String, _
    ByVal Recipient As String, _
    ByVal ToAdd As String, _
    ByVal strProgram As String, _
    ByVal Attachment As String, _
    ByVal strSubject As String, _
    ByVal strMessage As String, _
    ByVal strEmailFROM As String, _
    ByVal strEmailPWD As String, _
    Optional ByVal CC As String) As Boolean

    Dim cdoConfig As Object
    Dim msgOne As Object
    

On Error GoTo errHandler

EmailReceiptByGeneric = False
    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    With cdoConfig.Fields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465 '587 '
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = strEmailFROM
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = strEmailPWD
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
        
        .Update
    End With
    
    Set msgOne = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

        
    Set msgOne.Configuration = cdoConfig
    
    msgOne.To = ToAdd
    msgOne.FROM = strEmailFROM
    msgOne.Subject = strSubject
    msgOne.htmlBody = strMessage & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & _
        strReceipt
    
    msgOne.send
    EmailReceiptByGeneric = True


Cleanup:

    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next

exitProc:

    Exit Function
        
errHandler:
    EmailReceiptByGeneric = False
    MsgBox prompt:="There was an error in the attempt to send email through " & strEmailFROM & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, _
        buttons:=vbCritical + vbOKOnly, title:="Unable to Send Email through " & strEmailFROM
    Resume Cleanup
    Resume
    

End Function
Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(ByVal strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Dim blnIsValidEmail As Boolean

On Error GoTo errHandler
    strEmailAddress = Trim(strEmailAddress)
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$"
    blnIsValidEmail = objRegExp.Test(Trim(strEmailAddress))
    ValidateEmailAddress = blnIsValidEmail
 
Cleanup:

    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next

exitProc:

    Exit Function
        

errHandler:

    ValidateEmailAddress = False
    MsgBox prompt:=Err & ": " & Err.description, buttons:=vbCritical + vbOKOnly, title:="Unable to Validate Email"
    Resume Cleanup
    Resume
    
End Function

Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(ByVal strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Dim blnIsValidEmail As Boolean

On Error GoTo errHandler
    strEmailAddress = Trim(strEmailAddress)
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$"
    blnIsValidEmail = objRegExp.Test(Trim(strEmailAddress))
    ValidateEmailAddress = blnIsValidEmail
 
Cleanup:

    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next

exitProc:

    Exit Function
        

errHandler:

    ValidateEmailAddress = False
    MsgBox prompt:=Err & ": " & Err.description, buttons:=vbCritical + vbOKOnly, title:="Unable to Validate Email"
    Resume Cleanup
    Resume
    
End Function

Public Function ValidatePMT(ByVal dblPmtAmt As Double, ByVal dtPmtDate As Date) As Boolean

On Error GoTo errHandler

    If dblPmtAmt = 0 Then
        ValidatePMT = False
        MsgBox prompt:="Payment amount is required for emailed receipt.", buttons:=vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, title:="Missing Required Payment Amount"
        GoTo Cleanup
    ElseIf dtPmtDate = #1/31/2099# Then
        ValidatePMT = False
        MsgBox prompt:="Payment date is required for emailed receipt.", buttons:=vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, title:="Missing Required Payment Date"
        GoTo Cleanup
     End If
    ValidatePMT = True
    
Cleanup:

    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next

exitProc:

    Exit Function
        
errHandler:

    MsgBox prompt:="Unexpected error " & Err.Number & ", " & Err.description, buttons:=vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, title:="Error"
    Resume Cleanup
    Resume
    

End Function
```

Comment: Comment out the error handlers and see where the errors are.  Post back with details about any you see.

Comment: Your issue is most likely some security settings and not the code.   Did you upgrade recently?   Did you allow programmatic access to your email client?

Comment: @Sorceri, as far as I know, the only upgrade was bringing it to 64bit. how do i allow programmatic access?

Comment: @TimWilliams, the only error I get says "There was an error in the attempt to send email through [email address]

Comment: Comment out the line `On Error GoTo errHandler`  - where do you get an error?

Comment: @TimWilliams  -2147220975: The message could not be sent to the SMTP server. The transport error code was 0x80040217. The server response was not available.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "bringing it to 64 bit".  Do you mean that you installed Office 64Bit and expect Office 32Bit applications to work out of the box?  Unfortunately you're out of luck.  Essentially any Office 32bit VBA that references any external DLL or COM objects will need to be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you upgraded to new Windows...

Microsoft stopped including CDO with Windows, if I'm not mistaken, some 10 years ago.

You can solve this by obtaining the dll file

```
cdosys.dll
```

preferably from your previous Windows system, from the following folder.

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

Copy the dll to the same location on your new system.

Then you must register the dll on your new system. Open a COMMAND window and navigate to your C:\Windows\System32 folder and run the following command.

```
regsvr32 cdosys.dll
```